# HTTP Request processing in ABAP system

Tags: abap

I have a very basic question in how a external HTTP request is processed in an ABAP (S/4 system).

Are the requests handled by per process or per thread. (terms taken more from the java http world). ?

By threads will mean which already have the objects initialised in memory by the previous request.

By process will mean that the objects are initialised in memory every time which is obviously time consuming and non performant.

In case of a clustered system the request can be load balanced to a new systems which is a separate topic.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Internet Communication Manager (ICM) handle request and forward it to your class which is extend from IF_HTTP_EXTENSION interface by url (configure it in SICF).

SAP need authorization for accept http request. Web logon screen set cookie to client for tracking it. If you configure static user to your service on t-code SICF, you can add cookies to client (with http header in response) for tracking and checking it.

There is no cache for object in this interface, but you can create your own with static class attributes and other general function caching capabilities from ABAP. Please check below rest service api for sample project:
https://github.com/pacroy/abap-rest-api

Load balancers has cookie based route capabilities (session based) for finding correct system.

Comment: thanks for your reply...but i am still not clear whether ABAP Server holds the memory between two requests.

Comment: I am not sure but; SAP Netware using global, report based and user based and global caching capabilities, you can determine cache level with ABAP code. I wrote authentication information in my message. So I think created objects saved in service/logedin user cache. After idle time, user auto logout and cached objects removed.